# StackExchange Beta iPhone App - No Internet = No screen or message

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I didn't have internet on my iPhone today and tried the StackExchange app (I rely on you guys being online - as most people do with google).

All the other apps (FB, LI, etc) have a "No Internet Connection" message, the StackExchange app just comes up with the blue gradient/shaded background.

Dont think many people have encountered this, so I am letting SE know as a suggestion to have a message (so people know its their connection thats down not the SE app hanging on start up).

**edit**

It wasn't the first time I opened the app.

You're right the app opens in airplane mode (I am typing this offline).

I was ready for someone to comment "screenshot or it didn't happen" and this is what it looked like.
[image]

The weird thing was that I had reception, just no internet, maybe vodaphone was down and that's why no one else has seen this. Also terminating the app and restarting didn't fix it, I still got the empty blue background.

I do believe ShadowWizard that there would be a message like the one below when posting in airplane mode:

[image]

Happy to post logs (let me know where to find them). If there's any other diagnostic info I can provide let me know, maybe a dump or something, I don't know how to debug iOS/objectiveC apps but if I can repro it again then...

Comment: I'm quite sure it used to show such message. Are you sure you had no connection at all? In case of a very slow connection, the app simply try to connect to the server and probably have a long timeout.

Comment: Agree with @ShadowWizard. On airplane mode I get "The internet connection appears to be offline" (1.2.0.175)

Comment: Was this your first time using the app?  Had you already seen your feed and other things before?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I was checking and we have neither a good way of getting the logs out or meaningful info at startup.  I'm going to push out a new build that makes both better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update again**

This should be fixed in the next release, coming out by the end of January.  I identified the issue in [iOS app crashes on startup under slow internet connections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270802/ios-app-crashes-on-startup-under-slow-internet-connections) as there being unknown sites in the feed causing the app to lock up while trying to resolve them.

---

It sounds like you hit a bug where the main thread hung before completing `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  In that case terminating the app and resuming should have fixed it.

I've tried the beta and release apps both in Airplane mode and with 100% packet loss.  In both cases it would successfully render the feed and allow limited interaction in the app, such as viewing recently viewed or favorited questions.  When I got to new content either I would get an instant error (Airplane mode) or the spinner would just keep spinning (packet loss).

If you can reproduce getting stuck on the gradient screen, I'd like to see what we can get from your logs to help debug this.

---

**Update**

I've added the ability to send logs form then beta builds (and some additional logging at launch).  If you can reproduce the issue can you send the logs from the about screen of the app and let us know?

> [image]

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for looking into this. I edited question with more details.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I've updated the app so you should be able to send the logs if it happens again.  The app will keep between 1 and 2 days worth of logs.