# iOS app locked up

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

While loading a question the app froze.
A force-quit and restart lead to a blank blue screen.
Using the Return to Feed setting had no effect.
Using the task switcher froze the whole device; only the power button was responsive.
Rebooting the phone had no effect.
Setting Return to Feed after a reboot finally got everything back to normal.

iPhone 5S, iOS 9.2, app v1.4.1

Comment: Sounds like a device issue, you sure all other apps worked fine?

Comment: No problems with any other apps. The SE app almost did it again earlier when returning to the feed, but was able to recover without rebooting the phone.

Comment: I definitely can't take responsibility for locking up the whole OS.  I can't think of anything specific that would cause the app to freeze on question load but if the feed was loading simultaneously, there's [a bug with the feed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270802/ios-app-crashes-on-startup-under-slow-internet-connections) that could cause the app to freeze.  The fix will be in 1.4.3 in January.

Comment: If it deadlocks or burns some resource on an EnteredForeground notification or app delegate that might give the OS some trouble keeping up. Was on a slow and patchy network at the time, so it may all be that feed freeze.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed with yesterday's app store release. (1.4.3.7)

Please let me know if it resurfaces.